# Why Map is not showing in Mobile device?

Tags: android, css, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile
My Page

```
<div data-role="page" id="mapView" data-transition="slide">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>
                <a href="" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-mini="true" onclick="showDirection()">Get Direction</a></h1>
        </div>
         <p id="atmBoothDetails" >
            </p>
        <div data-role="content" id="mapViewContent">


            <div id="map-canvas">
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
#map-canvas
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }
```

**Why Map is not showing in Mobile device??**

Comment: Did any of the answers below solved your problem? If yes, then please check the one (I believe Gajotres provided an excellent answer), if not please provide an answer of your own and check that one.

Comment: I have forgotten to accept it. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Description

This is not enough. Your **`#map-cnvas`** <div> will cover only full size of content div. Unfortunately content div (**`data-role="content"`**) will never cover full available height left by header and footer.

That's why you need to manually resize content div height.

### Solution 1

#### CSS:

```
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

Working jsFiddle example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7kGdE/

Replace top and bottom with 0 if you don't have herader and footer.

### Solution 2

#### Javascript

```
function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();
 
    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    } 
    return content_height;
}
```

This is a javascript solution.

And here’s also a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xbr2v/

### Final notes

If you want to find more information about this problem take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)**, you will also find several working examples.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the page will take as little place as possible. You are using 100% for width and height, but the container of the page doesn't have an actual height. You will have to do that programmatically. Check  `$(window).height();` to take the actual height of your viewport and change the `#map-canvas` height. You will have to do some tweaks for any header and footer you might have.